# Failed to load resource CSS AND js libraries: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Tags: javascript, flask

I am unable to fetch the css and JavaScript files into my Flask project. The structure of css and JavaScript files is:

[image]

```
<!--  CSS Section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--  JS libraries -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

I have tried changing the file paths many times using like this:

```
<!--  CSS Section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/aos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--  JS libraries -->
<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

None of the method is not working.

I am expecting to fetch all of the CSS and JS libraries into my project.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it sorted. However, you should post an answer with a valid solution rather than thanking me. Take the [tour] for a refresher. If not, consider deleting your question rather than abandoning it.